# org.openntf.domino exception on getDocumentContext()

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'm trying to get the query string paramaters of an agent triggered from web:

```
http://myhost/mydb.nsf/myagent?open&reportID=96c6
```

Using org.openntf.domino API and running a Domino 9 server HF441 and  org.openntf.domino.xsp_1.0.0.201309021740

I get this exception:

```
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM: org.openntf.domino.exceptions.UndefinedDelegateTypeException
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getParentDatabase(Factory.ja
va:613)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.impl.Document.(Document.java:109)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.fromLotus(Factory.java:251)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at org.openntf.domino.impl.AgentContext.getDocumentContext(Agent
Context.java:85)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:25)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
[0D40:0045-1488] 2013-09-03 12:01:56   HTTP JVM:        at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.openntf.domino.AgentBase;
import org.openntf.domino.AgentContext;
import org.openntf.domino.Database;
import org.openntf.domino.Document;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    boolean debug = false;
    PrintWriter pw;

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            pw = getAgentOutput();
            Database reportDB = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),
                    "report.nsf");
            Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
            String qs = doc.getItemValueString("Query_String");
            Hashtable ht = CommonJ.parseQueryString(qs);
            String reportID = (String) ht.get("reportID");

            Document reportDoc = reportDB.getDocumentByID(reportID);
            if (null != reportDoc) {

                String filename = reportDoc.getFirstItem("$File")
                        .getValueString();
                pw.println(reportDoc.getHttpURL() + "/$file/" + filename);
            } else {
                pw.println("<h2>Sorry, report not found!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            pw.println("<h2>Sorry, report not found!");
            pw.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this in my current branch. If you're up to modifying and building from source yourself, this is the change:

https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/commit/08d48763c22c6cdbb411d37e792a80c84e56eb34

Specifically, in the "getCurrentDatabase" method of org.openntf.domino.impl.AgentContext, change the final "this" in the "fromLotus" call to "getCurrentDatabase()".

Alternatively, I exported a jar from my dev environment that fixed it in my test (this is basically M3 plus a slight bit of work in the Design tree as well as this fix):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23599916/org.openntf.domino-jesse-20130903.jar

Let me know if you still run into trouble!

Comment: Thx, that was fast ;)
Is it OK to wait for the M3 release? We have some dev servers and clients to deploy this to and I just did this for the latest rel of 2 sept...

Comment: Hmm, it'd possibly be worth it to release a quick patch version, since this bug could certainly be trouble.

Comment: Looks like Nathan beat me to it with a patch release: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/release.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects%5Cpmt.nsf&documentId=B58852B1EF615A8686257BDB004AD3B4&action=openDocument

Comment: You complete me, Jesse. :-)